# CDI Producer is always null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I'd like to create a producer annotation for some default user settings. I want to inject these settings for every new user creation. But my settings are always `null`. Why?

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,TYPE})
public @interface DefaultSettings {

}

public class UserSettings {
    public UserSettings() {}

    @Produces
    @DefaultSettings
    @RequestScoped
    public UserSettings getDefaultSettings() {
        UserSettings settings = new UserSettings();
        settings.doSomeConfiguration();
        return settings;
    }

    private void doSomeConfiguration() {
        //default initialisation
    } 
}

class User {
    @Inject
    @DefaultSettings
    private UserSettings settings; //always null
}
```

What is wrong or missing here?

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but you forgot to return `settings` in `getDefaultSettings`.

Comment: thanks, yes was just a typo here on SO.

Comment: @membersound I think you are a bit off track with this custom annotation. If you really want it to work, you need "someone", on runtime to deal with it. All you did now is create a annotation and annotate some classes with it. You might want to read a bit more about them.

Comment: Do you have `beans.xml` in your WEB-INF?

Comment: yes of course, empty beans.xml

Comment: how do you instantiate the User class?

Comment: also inject it into a `UserManager`

Comment: BTW is your the reference null or you're getting an exception? Because CDI throws an exception if a producer method with a non-dependent scope returns null.

Comment: I'm getting exactly a `NullPointerException`